I am working in the project bootsrap5 so for data I need to adjust calendar according to the Figma
I am working in the project bootstrap5 so for data I need  to adjust  calendar according  to the figma. For the moment my calendar is the just basis as you can see on the image:

But how I can adjust my code such us calendar on the Figma  is secondly image that I am attaching:

I tried to style class of the datapicker table but not at all works.


$(function() {
  $('input[name="daterange"]').daterangepicker({
    opens: 'right',
    locale: {
      format: 'MMM D, YYYY',
      applyLabel: 'Apliko', // Your "Apliko" button for apply
      cancelLabel: 'Cancel',
      daysOfWeek: ['MO', 'TU', 'WE', 'TH', 'FR', 'SA', 'SU'],
      monthNames: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'],
      firstDay: 1
    },
    startDate: moment().subtract(29, 'days'),
    endDate: moment(),
  });
});
.daterangepicker {
  width: 752px;
  height: 470px;
  border-radius: 9px;
  border: none;
  background: #FFF;
  box-shadow: 0px 16px 23.5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}

.daterangepicker:before {
  position: relative;
  border-right: none;
  border-left: none;
  top: 0;
}

.daterangepicker .drp-calendar {
  margin: 20px;
  width: 372px;
}

table>thead>tr:nth-child(1) {
  position: relative;
  width: 372px;
}

table>thead>tr:nth-child(1)::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: #BDBDBD;
}

.daterangepicker .calendar-table .prev span {
  /* background-image: url("/assets/images/chevron-left.png"); */
  border: solid #828282;
  border-width: 0 2px 2px 0;
  /* width: 21px;
        height: 21px */
}

.daterangepicker .calendar-table .month {
  color: #828282;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: normal;
}
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.6.0/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/moment@2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.js"></script>

<div class="container mt-5">
  <input type="text" name="daterange" class="form-control" placeholder="Start Date - End Date" id="datefilter">
</div>




I need to styles calendar based on the Figma inspect I tried to make this but don't work perfectly:


$(function() {
  $('input[name="daterange"]').daterangepicker({
    opens: 'right',
    locale: {
      format: 'MMM D, YYYY',
      applyLabel: 'Apliko',  // Your "Apliko" button for apply
      cancelLabel: 'Cancel',
      daysOfWeek: ['MO', 'TU', 'WE', 'TH', 'FR', 'SA', 'SU'],
      monthNames: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'],
      firstDay: 1
    },
    startDate: moment().subtract(29, 'days'),
    endDate: moment(),
  });
});
    .daterangepicker {
        width: 752px;
        height: 470px;
        border-radius: 9px;
        border: none;
        background: #FFF;
        box-shadow: 0px 16px 23.5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    }

    .daterangepicker:before {
        position: relative;
        border-right: none;
        border-left: none;
        top: 0;
    }

    .daterangepicker .drp-calendar {
        margin: 20px;
        width: 372px;
    }


    table>thead>tr:nth-child(1) {
        position: relative;
        width: 372px;
    }

    table>thead>tr:nth-child(1)::after {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        height: 1px;
        background-color: #BDBDBD;
    }

    .daterangepicker .calendar-table .prev span {
        /* background-image: url("/assets/images/chevron-left.png"); */
        border: solid #828282;
        border-width: 0 2px 2px 0;
        /* width: 21px;
        height: 21px */
    }

    .daterangepicker .calendar-table .month{
        color: #828282;
        text-align: center;
       
        font-size: 17px;
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: 600;
        line-height: normal;
    }
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.6.0/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/moment@2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container mt-5">
  <input type="text" name="daterange" class="form-control" placeholder="Start Date - End Date" id="datefilter">
</div>


</body>

</html>




Is this supposed to be an answer, an edit to your question above, or a new question?

This is more of a question than an answer.
